# TerminateProcess is not working when There is more than one process open

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I am using `CreateProcess` to run Adobe Acrobat Reader to display a PDF file. I would like to close that application. I am trying use `TerminatePocess` to close the application. If only one instance of the application is running, `TerminateProcess` works just fine. But if more than one instance is running, it will not close. If a PDF file is opened outside my program, and my program runs Acrobat Reader to open a different file, `TerminateProcess` will not close the reader that I opened.

I am using:

```
result = CreateProcess(NULL, LaunchExeCharString, NULL, NULL, FALSE, bWait ? HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS : NULL, NULL, WorkingPathName, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInformation);
```

Where `LaunchExeCharString` is the name of the reader (AcroRd32.exe).

`StartupInfo` is the following:

```
StartupInfo.cb              = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
StartupInfo.lpReserved      = NULL;
StartupInfo.lpDesktop       = NULL;
StartupInfo.lpTitle         = NULL;
StartupInfo.dwX             = 0;
StartupInfo.dwY             = 0;
StartupInfo.dwXSize         = 0;
StartupInfo.dwYSize         = 0;
StartupInfo.dwXCountChars   = 0;
StartupInfo.dwYCountChars   = 0;
StartupInfo.dwFillAttribute = 0;
StartupInfo.dwFlags         = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartupInfo.wShowWindow     = RunMode;
StartupInfo.cbReserved2     = 0;
StartupInfo.lpReserved2     = NULL;
StartupInfo.hStdInput       = NULL;
StartupInfo.hStdOutput      = NULL;
StartupInfo.hStdError       = NULL;
```

Then I use

```
TerminateProcess(ProcessInformation.hProcess, 0);
```

Like I said, if another PDF file is open, TerminateProcess will not terminate my instance of acrord32.exe.  It only works if I was the only one to run acrord32.

Comment: You might have to find the window (using EnumWindow) and then send WM_CLOSE to that window.

Answer (score 3):

`CreateProcess()` can only give you a `HANDLE` to the process that it directly created.  Sometimes, an app might launch another process of its own to do its work, or it might pass information (like the passed filename) to another running process and then exit itself.  Those kind of behaviors would account for the symptoms you are seeing, if that is what Adobe is doing internally.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you launch an instance of Adobe Reader, and user *reads* the PDF content. But who are you to decide *when* the Reader is supposed to close? Let the end-user decide when the said application is to close. Are you waiting for few seconds/minutes before application should close - that's a bad design. Are you providing user an option in your application (like some `Close Adobe Reader` button), when you application should close - not a good option!

For just launching application, you should just use `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` to **open** the desired file. The OS (i.e. *Shell*) will determine how to open a particular file. How do you know where Adobe Reader is installed - in `Program Files`, or in `Program Files (x86)`. Which version of Reader is installed? And what about any other application, say a word-processor, or a media player? Who are you to open a file using **very-specific** program to open a file, and you to decide when to terminate such process.

More than that, your application may spawn other process(es) - would you close all child processes (down the process-tree)?